# How to convert a String containing multiple JSON Objects into actual JSON Objects in Java

Tags: java, json, rest, request

I'm working on an application that is supposedly a game of some sorts and for the purpose of saving data and making it accesible to multiple clients I have set up a REST Backend API that just distributes and updates game data from and to other players.

I have worked out how to make 'GET' and other requests to the API but in the process of a general 'GET' request, which - server sided - returns a list of all available objects in a resource I get a return String saying

```
    [{"id": 0, "ownerid": 0, "position": [0,0], "size": 1}, {"id": 1, "ownerid": 0, "position": [0,0], "size": 1}]
```

So naturally I would need to parse these into multiple JSONObjects. However whenever I try to do that using logical approaches the compiler tells me that this is wrong because of the [] surrounding the entire response entity.

This is the litteral error code copied from the console:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:505)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:215)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:399)
    at Game.Game.<init>(Game.java:36)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Here's the code I use to convert:

```
    Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget wt = c.target("http://localhost:3000").path("villages");
    Invocation.Builder invBuild = wt.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Response res = invBuild.get();

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(res.readEntity(String.class));
    String[] ids = JSONObject.getNames(json);
    JSONArray arr = json.toJSONArray(new JSONArray(ids));
```

The current code there is as read from another StackOverflow post but, as said, it doesn't work because of the [] surrounding the response String.

The used Libraries for the request - response client logic are taken from the Jersey Libraries.

Comment: What you get is a JSON **array**, not a JSON **object**. An object starts with `{`. An array starts with `[`.

Comment: Holy Jesus i thought so much about it and it's that simple. Shoot me.